# How do I see my entire UV map with UV sync selection off?

Tags: uv, vertices, faces, uv-image-editor, selection-tools

I'm trying to move a few vertices around on one island only.

I want to move them so that they are in line with another island.

With sync UV selection turned on I can see the 2 islands but if I move the vertices their connected vertices on all the other islands move.

So I need to turn sync selection off. But when I do this the unselected portions of the UV map disappear. So I can't see where I'm moving the vertices in relation to the other islands.

How do I work with uv sync selection off and also see the unselected vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without *UV Sync Selection* you can choose a different *Sticky Selection Mode*: the default is *Shared Vertex*, but you can also select *Shared Location* or - what might be better in your case - *Disabled*.

If you now have the complete mesh selected in *Edit Mode*, you can freely select vertices, edges, faces or islands in the *UV Editor*.

[image: uv sticky selection]

Comment: Ah I see - so what's visible in the UV panel is determined by the selection in the edit window. This makes total sense now. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, correct. And you can choose this method to create new islands. You see, in my example image the UV map of the default cube is usually this single island cross shape. So with island select you would always select everything. But if you switch to face select and select one or more faces and move them away so that they are separate, you've now created one or more new islands.