# I cannot alter a UV island without affecting verts on other islands

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I am in the UV editor and am trying to straighten up some UV islands. If I grab an edge or row of verts and try to move or scale them, these verts grab verts on other islands and scales or moves them too. This has put me at a standstill. Also, straighten verts or edges isn't having any effect whatsoever.

[image]

Comment: Have you marked any seams before UV unwrapping your object? Suggest you share your blend file so that we can have a look: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Yes I marked seams and used the auto UV unwrap tool. Are you saying seams affect this? Why would it?

Comment: I cleared the seams and redid the UV unwrap and the same thing is happening. I select an edge to edit, say scale it to straighten it, and the pivot point gizmo flies to the center of the whole unwrap, because Blender is grabbing verts elsewhere. So frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

Turn Off UV Sync

[image]

Or Hide the faces that you don't need to be move (In face selection) <kbd>H</kbd>

Comment: Thanks--but how do I turn that off and still get to see all the faces?

Comment: Select your 3D object on the 3D viewport ("A "on your keyboard) to see the whole UV's

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/245286/how-do-i-see-my-entire-uv-map-with-uv-sync-selection-off